# Global menubar in Libreoffice 4.1 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: libreoffice, ppa, globalmenu

Is there any way to install lo-menubar for Libreoffice 4.1 installed from the official Libreoffice ppa in Ubuntu 12.04?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This workaround does work partially, but has a very significant bug:

Download [lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lo-menubar/lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) for amd64 or [lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lo-menubar/lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb) for i386

extract

```
home/downloads/lo-menubar_0.1.1-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
```

with file roller

and sudo copy this folder:

```
home/downloads/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/menubar
```

to

```
file system/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/
```

NOTE: Libreoffice will integrate into global menubar, but you will only be able to access the menu via the HUD [pressing ALT on your keyboard]. Accessing via the actual menubar will cause libreoffice to crash. I have created a bug report at bugs.launchpad.net/lo-menubar/+bug/1216517

- EDIT:

If the bug affects you as well, feel free to mark yourself as affected in the bug report :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can install it, open your terminal and type below command or, install it from [Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lo-menubar/)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lo-menubar
```

Comment: It says it has some unresolved dependencies...

Comment: "depends on libreoffice-gtk. Can not install, you have corrupt packages..."

Comment: I get the same unresolved dependencies message as @holden87

Answer (score -2):

the menubar plugin is incompatibel with LO 4.1

Comment: Which menubar plugin? A plugin for Unity or for LibreOffice? And where to download? And how to install? This answer isn't very useful in its current form, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you read his question you know what I meant, see: [https://launchpad.net/lo-menubar]. The functionality is merge in LOs GTK2 VCL plugin eg. libreoffice-gtk which is sadly DE specific.